# How to Compare SolidColorBrushes?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to Compare 2 Brushes as you can see in the Picture. I have no Idea why its failing...

[image: Equal Fail]

Comment: There are probably other properties that are checked as well as color. If you just want to compare by color you are better off just doing that

Comment: Show your code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: Check the color and other properties of interest. `brush1.Color == brush2.Color`  should work.

Comment: Here is a useful comparison for all brush types: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/510614/WPF-Compare-two-brushes-using-IsEquals

Comment: `DependencyObject.Equals`: "This implementation is reference equality only, and does not attempt to evaluate value equality of the contained properties." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa345743(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Caramiriel, it is not this method which is called, but yes I think you are right, it is a reference comparison :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They won't be equal because it's doing a reference comparison and they are two different references in the heap with the same properties.

If you want to control object comparisons, you should implement the `IEqualtable` interface. You can then say how the objects must be compared. In this case however, since `SolidColorBrush` is a .NET class, we cannot implement  `IEquatable`. There are different options

1) Use an extension method on the `SolidColorBrush` which compares a brush instance with another. Not a very good solution in this case though.

2) The best bet would proably be to use `IEqualityComparer` interface. You create a seperate class implementing `IEqualityComparer`, which will define how to compare 2 different objects. For instance in your example, you may want to compare the SolidColorBrush on Color and Opacity:

```
public class SolidColorBrushComparer : IEqualityComparer<SolidColorBrush>
{
    public bool Equals(SolidColorBrush x, SolidColorBrush y)
    {
        return x.Color == y.Color && 
            x.Opacity == y.Opacity;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SolidColorBrush obj)
    {
        return new { C = obj.Color, O = obj.Opacity }.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then to compare you simply do the following:

```
SolidColorBrush otherBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFEFEEEE"));
SolidColorBrush backgroundBrush = (SolidColorBrush)grd.Background;

if(new SolidColorBrushComparer().Equals(backgroundBrush, otherBrush))
{
   // They're equal, Yay!
}
```

Comment: Your `GetHashCode` implementation isn't compliant with `Equals` implementation. You'll be surprised if you use your `SolidColorBrushComparer` with `HashSet`, key in `Dictionary` or any other hash table data structure.

Comment: Thanks @SriramSakthivel for spotting that, I've fixed the post accordingly.

Comment: Still there is a little bit problem you're checking floating point for equality; that may fail. Let's leave that to readers; now it's worth an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Classes derived from `DependencyObject` will only be equal (`.Equals() == true`) if the object has the same reference (overloading not included). This can only be the case if the actual same object was used, or `BrushConverter.ConvertFrom` was returning the same instances of the `SolidColorBrush`. This case is unlikely, and would be an assumption.

Like comments already mentioned: try to compare the `Color` and/or other properties of the solid color brush. `Color` is a struct that implements `IEquatable<Color>` and will result in the correct behavior.

Sources:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa345743(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I skinned the cat as follows, comparing the hexadecimal values as strings:

```
if (MyBrush.ToString() == Brushes.Transparent.ToString())
    MyBrush = Brushes.Magenta;
```

I was forced to find another way besides those previously mentioned because I'm using C# within another framework that has some limitations (e.g. the `.Color` property is not available to me).