# WPF: Equals(Control.background, SolidColorBrush) constantly false

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `List<SolidColorBrush> lColorBrushes` and want to compare the Background of some Buttons with it's content. The Buttons are saved in `List<Button> lClickedButtons`.

```
            foreach (var oBtn in lClickedButtons)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < lColorBrushes.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Equals(oBtn.Background, lColorBrushes[i]))
                    {
                        //oBtn gets cool stuff
                    }
                }
            }
```

I did the exact same thing earlier and it worked tottaly fine. But for whatever reason (I dont see any difference to earlier circumstances of my Code) now the if condition is constantly false. Also if for example `oBtn.Background` and `lColorBrushes[i]` both are `#FFFF0000`.

Comment: Possibly related to `SolidColorBrush` being `Freezable`, as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)

Comment: `#FFFF0000` isn't a brush; it's a color. `new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0xff, 0, 0)) != new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0xff, 0, 0))` -- two different brush objects.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for `Equals()` returning false, is that these are two entirely different references, that just happen to have the same `Color` property.

If you want to compare the two SolidColorBrushes, I suggest you use the `IEqualityComparer` interface, as such: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105339/how-to-compare-solidcolorbruhes)).

```
public class SolidColorBrushComparer : IEqualityComparer<SolidColorBrush>
{      
    public bool Equals(SolidColorBrush x, SolidColorBrush y)
    {
        // If you do not care about opacity, disregard it.
        return x.Color == y.Color && 
            x.Opacity == y.Opacity;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SolidColorBrush obj)
    {
        return new { C = obj.Color, O = obj.Opacity }.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it inside your loop as follows:

```
foreach (var oBtn in lClickedButtons)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < lColorBrushes.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (new SoldiColorBrushComparer().Equals(oBtn.Background, lColorBrushes[i]))
                    {
                        //oBtn gets cool stuff
                    }
                }
            }
```