# Problems when trying to change HEX values in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my MainWindows.xaml I have a rectangle with `Fill="#95305D"`
I want to change its color with a different Hex color on click so I tried:

```
    public void Rect_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RMaximize.Fill == (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#95305D"))
            RMaximize.Fill = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#3E7A61");
        else
            RMaximize.Fill = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#95305D");
    }
```

It did not work however, I'm getting no errors but also no changes, how can I do this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105339/how-to-compare-solidcolorbrushes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when BrushConverter converts string, it creates a new SolidColorBrush. SolidColorBrush is a reference type. when you compare it with `RMaximize.Fill`, you compare two references, which are different.

while it is possible to compare colors of brushes, I would refactor code as follows:

```
private SolidColorBrush _b1 = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#95305D");
private SolidColorBrush _b2 = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#3E7A61");
private int clickCount = 0;

public void Rect_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    clickCount++;
    RMaximize.Fill = (clickCount % 2 == 1) ? _b2 : b1;
}
```

I introduced a new variable to count the number of clicks and change Fill for odd or even clicks

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense just a little typo : b1 = _b1